# Sharing same axes in python matplotlib - losing date format and graphng in opposite parts of the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I'm trying to create one single plot containing different values from two different data frames with a shared index.

I'm able to do it in two separate graphs using the following code:

```
# Initialize the plot figure
fig = plt.figure()
# Add a subplot and label for y-axis
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211,  ylabel='Price in $')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212,  ylabel='Price in $')
# Plot the closing price
btc['Weighted Price'].plot(ax=ax1, color='m', lw=2.,figsize=(10, 8))
# Plot the short and long moving averages
signals[['short_mavg', 'long_mavg']].plot(ax=ax1, lw=2.)
# Plot the buy signals
ax2.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == 1.0].index, signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == 1.0],'^', markersize=10, color='g')     
# Plot the sell signals
ax2.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == -1.0].index, signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == -1.0], 'v', markersize=10, color='k')     
# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

and this is the result I get:
[Two graphs with same axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNLdu.png)

When I try doing the same proces but just calling one subplot (ax1), using the following sintax, the result is not what I was waiting for, the x axis loses its "Date" format, and both series graph at opposite sides of the graph.

```
# Initialize the plot figure
fig = plt.figure()
# Add a subplot and label for y-axis
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,  ylabel='Price in $')
# Plot the closing price
btc['Weighted Price'].plot(ax=ax1, color='m', lw=2.,figsize=(10, 8))
# Plot the short and long moving averages
signals[['short_mavg', 'long_mavg']].plot(ax=ax1, lw=2.)
# Plot the buy signals
ax1.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == 1.0].index,signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == 1.0],'^', markersize=10, color='g')
# Plot the sell signals
ax1.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == -1.0].index,signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == -1.0],'v', markersize=10, color='k')
# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

This is the graph that comes out:[One graph with wrong values and date values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV9jr.png)

Anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Pandas does some pretty fancy handling of dates in their plotting methods. So mixing them with matplotlib methods gets tricky. If you're plotting with dates, the overly simplified answer is that you need to pick an API and stick with it.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I'm pretty new to all this. Could you expand a bit?

Comment: If you want to notify @PaulH you need to use the @ notation. What he means by this comment is that you want to decide if you want to plot all your plots using the matplotlib methods (e.g. `ax.plot()`, `ax.scatter()` etc) or the pandas methods, (e.g. `df.plot(ax=ax)`). Trying to mix the two ways for the same (or different shared) plot(s) will fail if dates are involved.